# Need help identifying function of odd looking switch/connection/??? mounted to 2nd story Fascia

Tags: electrical, switch, junction-box

This photo is zoomed in on a gang box that is mounted to the 2nd story exterior Fascia of my buddy's log cabin.  We are trying to figure out what this is for as neither of us have seen this before.  Its not an easy spot to get to so I am hopeful someone recognizes this thing and can provide a clue as to what it might be for.

[image]

Comment: Yes there is an alarm, you think that has something to do with it it?

Answer (score 3):

It’s a photocell, to turn something on at dusk off at dawn.

[Pictured here is Intermatics product](https://www.1000bulbs.com/product/3319/ELEC-K4321C.html?gclid=EAIaIQobChMI8NnVwsf13QIVwcDACh0yLgqvEAQYAyABEgKjrPD_BwE) several companies make look a alike.

[image]

Comment: Ahhhhh now its adding up real fast, ha... The floodlights are motion activated and as soon as I read your response I remember his comment that he couldn't find a switch for the floodlights which would mean they would have been going off all day if something wasnt triggering dusk/dawn.  I guess I figured that was built into the motion detector.

Comment: Usually that is built into the motion detector.  Perhaps original design was photocell and somebody added motion later.

Comment: Gotcha, yes that has to be it.  Thank you sir!

Comment: No, usually the "don't turn on during the daytime" feature is built into the motion detector.  The reason is you don't want to sever power to sensors, because then they forget what they learned over time about the lay of the land, normal day/night light levels here, etc. and have to re-learn from scratch everytime.